# IOS playing short sound

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I'm trying to play a short alarm sound in my iphone application
i'm using this code i found but it won't play any sound.

```
NSString *toneFilename = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"alarm" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *toneURLRef = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:toneFilename];
    SystemSoundID Sound;

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(
                                     (__bridge CFURLRef) toneURLRef,
                                     &camerSound
                                     );

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(Sound);
```

when i try to make vibration it works though :

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

Thx

Comment: try on device, forget simulator

Answer (score 3):

Using AVFoundationFramework

Add the `AVFoundation.framework` to project.

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

NSString *toneFilename = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"alarm" ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL *toneURLRef = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:toneFilename];
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: toneURLRef error: nil];
player.currentTime = 0;
player.volume = 1.0f;
[player play];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not addressing your `Sound` variable correctly when creating the sound. Instead you are using `camerSound`. Calling the `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound` with the correct parameter should work.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfect for me.

Add AVFoundation and AudioToolBox frameworks into the project

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController
{
    SystemSoundID SoundID;
}

@implementation TestViewController
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"caf"];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)url, &SoundID);  //When using ARC, make sure to use __bridge
 }

-(void) playSound {
     AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
 }
```